# Change of variables from intinite to bounded support.

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I may be missing something simple, but I am stuck.  My question:

I am solving a system of partial differential equations numerically, but one of the variables can take on any value, ie $x \in (-\infty, \infty)$, but in order to discretize the state space I need $x$ to be bounded.  Can anyone suggest a simple, invertible function such that $f(x): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, 1]$, or any other bounded interval for that matter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arctangent function is a nice bijective map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. It also happens to be monotonic, which is sometimes a desirable property when trying to decide between other possible maps. If necessary, you can transform the range into any open interval you wish by scaling and shifting.

Comment: Great idea.  It has been so long since I've taken a calculus course that I would not have thought of a trigonometric funciton.  Thanks!

Comment: @pdevar If for some reason you wanted to avoid transcendental functions, you might be interested to know that there are also a number of suitable rational functions that do the trick.